# SQLAlchemy, Flask and extracting using filter_by and filter

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application in which I am using SQLAlchemy.

I have a model:

```
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger, Column, JSON, Text
from app import db

class Table_910(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table_910'

    id = db.Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    did = db.Column(Text)
    timestamp = db.Column(BigInteger)
    data = db.Column(JSON)
    db_timestamp = db.Column(BigInteger)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<1_Data %r, %r>' % (self.did, self.id)
```

In my views part I am trying to extract a set of rows based on did and timestamp as I only want a subset of data.

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app, db, models

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    rows = models.Table_910.query \
        .filter_by(did='357139052424715') \
        .filter((db.Table_910.timestamp > 1466846920000) | (db.Table_910.timestamp < 1467017760000))

    return render_template('index.html', rows=rows)
```

But for some reason I am getting:

```
AttibuteError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'Table_910'.
```

Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: Please explain why you think I should get a down-vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Error message states you try to access `Tables_910` on the SQLAlchemy object. But your model is defined in the models.py. You need to use `models.Table_910` for your query.

Comment: Thanks. Such a simple solution! I can't believe I didn't try this first O.o